# Add mutliple Lists to one list

Tags: c#, linq, list, design-patterns

I have multiple functions that returns a List of objects. How can I add them into one list.

```
var List1 = GetList1().RunFilter1();
var List2 = GetList2();
```

The AddRange() function gets far to messy.

```
List1.AddRange(List2.AddRange(List3.AddRange(List4.AddRange(...);
```

Is there a pattern that I can use that it will be easier. I also have extension methods (Filters) that apply to certain lists. Which I interchange based on requirement.
Something like this:

```
var CombinedList = GetAllLists(GetList1().RunFilter1(),
                               GetList2(),
                               GetList3().RunFilter2(),
                               GetList4() ...);
```

Keep in mind that the GetList() functions being fetched might change.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe `Append` method... integrating all lists into one by that...

Comment: In the end, do you need a single list, or a single IEnumerable?  If you need a single list, DLeh's answer gives you that.  If you just need an IEnumerable but you don't really need to combine them into a list, then Christos' solution gives that.  If you don't need an actual single List, then Christos solution avoids the creation of that and is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some Linq extensions to help you out with the format a bit

```
var joined = GetList1()
    .Concat(GetList2())
    .Concat(GetList3().RunFilter())
    ...
    ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first insert all your lists into another list:

```
var temp = new List<T>
{
    GetList1().RunFilter1(),
    GetList2(),
    GetList3().RunFilter2(),
    GetList4() 
};
```

Then using the `SelectMany` method flatten this list.

```
var combined = temp.SelectMany(item=>item).ToList();
```

Comment: Using SelectMany() will yield an IEnumerable<>T without creating a new list, which is efficient.